# Easiest way to remove nested tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tags, nested

I am looking for the easiest way (coding and execution time) to remove nested tags from a DOM element using javascript.

**Example case**:

```
<i><b>This <b><i>is <u>a</u> new</i></b> test</b></i>
```

**Wanted solution**:

```
<i><b>This is <u>a</u> new test</b></i>
```

**The solution needs to work generally with all possible html tags and not just for the above example.**
All nested tags need to be eliminated while keeping the inner HTML in the DOM.

The solution may but doesn't need to use jQuery.

Any suggestions?

Comment: i didn't try anything so far, but was interrested in an easy solution to this problem

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes. I asked for the solution to a well defined problem.

Comment: `All nested tags` What about `div`'s?

Comment: taken the case my dom element is a div then i want to remove nested tags from this divs innerHTML (but keep the innerHTML of all nested elements)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try that for simplicity:

```
$("body *").each(function () {
    if ($(this).parents(this.nodeName.toLowerCase()).length) $(this).contents().unwrap();
});
```

### -DEMO-

Comment: That's impressive but I believe the answer from @Chris is more simple and understandable.

Comment: @eugensunic But OP said: `The solution needs to work generally with all possible html tags and not just for the above example`

Comment: The second I posted my comment I thought about that. Voting on your question tomorrow since I ran out of votes.

Comment: works. this goes into the direction i was thinking of. a demo is very nice too (plus one)

Comment: honestly, i do not think this can be done easier than this - if i am wrong post the solution here and i will switch the accepted answer

Answer (score 2):

Using the `find` method you could search for all children of the `<b>` tag inside the `<i>` tag:

**JS:**

```
$('i b').find('b', 'i').contents().unwrap();
```

Comment: This is not what the OP wants, the words are getting removed...

Comment: Sorry didnt see that part... apologies, I updated my answer

Comment: this won't work for tags inside the choosen html element that are nested themselves. counter-example: <i><u><u>text</u></u></i>

Comment: @Thariama you're right... WOW this one is quite intense. Is it even possible considering that you could have millions of different configurations?

Comment: i think so, A. Wolffs solution works and i am not sure if it can be done easier than that (but i give you plus one for your effort so far)

Comment: Thanx! Agreed A. Wolffs solution is super.

Answer (score 1):

This is a minor improvement to A.Woffs solution regarding code execution.
This way one jQuery element less gets initialized per dom node.
But i won't change the accepted answer to this answer for such a minor improvement.

```
$("body *").each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.parents(this.nodeName.toLowerCase()).length) $this.contents().unwrap();
});
```